# why no data is getting inserted for this stored pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I have created following function to check whether date exist in valid format.

```
create or replace function dt_valid(p_dstrng in varchar2,
                                    p_dfmt   in varchar2) return boolean is
  v_dtval date;
begin
  v_dtval := TO_DATE (p_dstrng, p_dfmt);
  return True;
exception
  when OTHERS then
    return False;
end;
```

The function is called  from PL/SQL
The procedure fetches metadata information from table tmp_to_dest and if the field it fetches is date ( identified by column transform_function = 'txt2dtf' )  it checks for format 'DD-MON-YY' for all the rows for that column in table.it does same for all the column in table temp_med. If that format is not present then row should get inserted in data_quality_chk .

```
create or replace procedure data_quality_check ( id number default null ) as
X varchar2(4000);
begin
for o in ( select temp_field_name,dest_field_name,transform_function from TMP_TO_DEST )
loop
   if o.transform_function = 'text2df'  then  
/// fetches the column name from metadata table TMP_TO_DEST and than loop through for each column to check for valid date
  for m in ( select o.temp_field_name temp_field_name from TEMP_COLUMNS )
     loop
    if not dt_valid(m.temp_field_name, 'DD-MON-YY') then
     execute immediate 'insert into data_quality_chk values(X,''1'',''1'',''1'',''1'') ' ;
     commit;
     END IF; 
     end loop;
  end if;
end loop;
end data_quality_check;

/// fetches the column name from metadata table TMP_TO_DEST and than loop through for each column to check for valid date
```

If I execute above procedure neither any output is displayed not any row get inserted.
Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: All anyone can tell by looking at it is it's full of odd things like a date validator function being applied to column names (or "field" names, whatever those are), a redundant `execute immediate` that can't work, a `commit` within a nested loop, and very little attempt to format the code for readability. Perhaps there is no data in `TMP_TO_DEST`? Perhaps the real procedure has a `when others` exception handler? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is mistake in the line:

```
if o.transform_function = 'text2df'  then
```

Try to change to this:

```
if o.transform_function = 'text2dtf'  then
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if the code is actually running coz i can see few error in both your function and in your proc. Please see the revised codes.

You can change your function as below:

```
 create or replace function dt_valid(p_dstrng in varchar2,
                                        p_dfmt   in varchar2) 
    return number is
    v_dtval date;
    begin

   v_dtval := TO_DATE (p_dstrng, p_dstrng);

      return 0;
    exception
      when OTHERS then
        return 1;
    end;
```

Call:

```
select dt_valid('12-SEP-16', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

Output

```
 SQL> select dt_valid('12-SEP-16', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;

DT_VALID('12-SEP-16','DD-MON-YY')
---------------------------------
                                0
```

And then use the return from the fucntion in your procedure inplace of any boolean.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data_quality_check (id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
AS
   X   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
  FOR o IN (SELECT temp_field_name, dest_field_name, transform_function
               FROM TMP_TO_DEST)
   LOOP
     IF lower(o.transform_function) = 'text2df'
      THEN   
         for m in ( select temp_field_name temp_field_name from TEMP_COLUMNS )  ---Must be throwing error coz of o.temp_field_name. O is not alaised to anything
          loop
           if  dt_valid(m.temp_field_name, 'DD-MON-YY') = 0 then
              execute immediate 'insert into data_quality_chk values(''X'',''1'',''1'',''1'',''1'') ';

           END IF;
          end loop;
     end if;
  end loop;
 commit;
END data_quality_check;
```